# Menu selector not accepting valid input

Tags: c++, debugging

When I enter “1” (without quotes) as input, it takes me to the error menu (invalid input).

To rephrase:
When I run through the program, at either the initial shape prompt menu or the ‘invalid entry’ menu, I’m unable to proceed to selection ‘1’ if I enter that as input.

Does anyone have some insight into what’s going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string username;
    cout<<"Hello.\nMy name is Pythagoras.\nI will be helping you build shapes today.\n\nWhat is your name?\n"<<endl;
    cin>>username;
    int shapeselect;
    cout<<"Hello, "<<username<<".\nWhat shape would you like to build today?\n1)Rectangle/Square\n2)Triangle\n3)Random!\n(Please select a number.)\n"<<endl;
    cin>>shapeselect;

    while (shapeselect!=1||shapeselect!=2||shapeselect!=3)
    {
        cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout<<"Sorry, "<<username<<", your entry was invalid.  Please select a valid number.\n";
        cout<<"What shape would you like to build today, "<<username<<"?\n1)Rectangle/Square!\n2)Triangle!\n3)Random!"<<endl;
        cin>>shapeselect;
    }

    if (shapeselect==1)
    {
        int width;
        cout<<"\nPlease enter the desired WIDTH of the rectangle, between 4 and 10.\n(Please select a number.)\n";
        cin>>width;
        cout<<"\nYou have selected a width of "<<width<<"."<<endl;
        int length;
        cout<<"\nPlease enter the desired LENGTH of the rectangle, between 4 and 10.\n(Please select a number.)\n";
        cin>>length;
        cout<<"\nYou have selected a length of "<<length<<"."<<endl;
        if (width==length)
        {
            cout<<"Please note that you have selected a width of "<<width<<" and a length of "<<width<<".\nNote that this shape will be a square.\n"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think a little bit about the condition `shapeselect!=1||shapeselect!=2||shapeselect!=3`. If you enter e.g. `1` as input, then the first part (`shapeselect!=1`) will be false and we continue to the next (`shapeselect!=2`) which will be *true*. And that makes the whole combined condition true. Time to learn about [De Morgans law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) and how to negate conditions.

Comment: It becomes obvious if you spell it: "if n not equal to 1 or n not equal to 2..." Every integer is not equal to 1 or not equal to 2. It hardly can be 1 _and_ 2. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, you need the while loop to execute when shapeselect is some number other than 1,2,3.

*To solve the problem replace all OR gates in the condition of while with AND gates.*

Reason: Because, OR gate outputs true when either of its' inputs are true. So If shapeselect is equal to 1 then it wont be equal to 2 and 3, which makes `shapeshelect!=2` and `shapeselect!=3` evaluate to true.
The while loop'll always run no matter which number you enter.